# implicitly unwrapping an Optional value on custom cell of table view

Tags: ios, swift, null, option-type

first of all i'm saying straight forward I know this is "duplicate" and and this is my 2nd time asking the same question - the problem is that my first one has been closed without me understanding the problem so please if someone wants to close this question again first let me understand what am I doing wrong. The solution I got last time was not relevant so if I could get addressed specifically that would be great!

I am trying to create a custom cell on tableview from an array. when I append any filed on my custom cell I get unexpected nil on all of the fileds and I have no idea why

**this is my custom cell:**

```
class CustomMovieCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rating: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseYear: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var genre: UILabel!
    var imageBackground: String!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

and this is my **UITableView** **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomMovieCell
        let movieFetched = Movie(title: moviesArray[indexPath.row].title, image: moviesArray[indexPath.row].image, rating: moviesArray[indexPath.row].rating, releaseYear: moviesArray[indexPath.row].releaseYear, genre: moviesArray[indexPath.row].genre)
        print(movieFetched)
        cell.title.text? = movieFetched.title
        cell.rating.text? = String(movieFetched.rating)
        cell.releaseYear.text? = String(movieFetched.releaseYear)
        cell.genre.text? = String(movieFetched.genre[0])
        return cell

    }
```

what am I missing? when appending ANY of the files I get unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value - I did not know UIlabel as IBOutlet are optional? even-though they are not optional in my custom cell class.

when debugging I can see that all values of the cell - title, image, rating, releaseYear and genre are nil when trying to assign them a value - so I really have no idea what to do at this point. I have deleted and re-created the cell from scratch and it did not make any differents.

As I already stated -  I know this is "duplicate". please though - do not close it before you help me because I did not get any answer the last time, I got directed to a wall-of-text page that did not help me understand my issue. The other "duplicate" pages are like a general "what are optional values" kind of question and do not help me with this specific issue.

edit: 
I have uploaded this project to github if it helps anyone help me to figure out this issue

https://github.com/alonsd/MoviesApi

Comment: Do you have prototype cell CustomMovieCell in storyboard? Have you connected all iboutlets properly?

Comment: It would be better for us if you can share the sample project with us

Comment: @AlonShlider link not found

Comment: **Moderator Note** - Please [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) in the comment section.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR fixed 
mag_zbc sorry for being rude before, I have been with this issue for many hours stright and it drove me nuts. 
and for the IBOutlets they are connected correctly as far as I see, what indecation do I have that it is not connected correctly?

Comment: Ok, that's stupid, but: get rid of `weak` in `CustomMovieCell` properties' definition. Even if the properties are connected and properly initialized, they will be deallocated due to not having any strong references.

Comment: As for accusing you of not doing any research prior, that was premature and I apologize. Doing review queues and seeing the exact same question for 123rd time each day makes you annoyed

Comment: done that, still getting nil on all of the cells fields. 
I have wrote a very similar project that does not have this issue and this is really frustrating hahaha

Comment: You changed `@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!` to `@IBOutlet var title: UILabel!`, you are sure it's connected in Interface Builder and it's still `nil` when you dequeue the cell?

Comment: yeah, just tried that - of all the files are nil even after deleting the "weak" keywork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've connected the custom cell class with 2 cells. One is in xib and another one is in this `UIViewController`. This `UIViewController's` prototype cell doesn't have these labels. So it will be nil and it will crash

Delete the prototype cell from `MoviesViewController` in storyboard. And add this in `MoviesViewController` `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MovieCell")
```

Change `tableView cellForRowAt` method as follows

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.title.text = moviesArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell.rating.text = String(moviesArray[indexPath.row].rating)
    cell.releaseYear.text = String(moviesArray[indexPath.row].releaseYear)
    cell.genre.text = String(moviesArray[indexPath.row].genre[0])

    return cell

}
```

Comment: did that, and still does not work. and as mag zbc sayed, if it was true it would crash on dequeueReusableCell and not on the cell properties. So I am stuck again with the files being nil.

Comment: @AlonShlider Check updated answer tableView.registerNib

Comment: @mag_zbc TableViewCell class is assigned to a xib and a prototype cell in a view controller. xib has labels and connected to custom class. another prototype cell which is in viewcontroller doesn't have labels but it is a valid cell. So he gets cell but not labels

Comment: HALELOYA! thank you very much! that finally fixed the issue. 
if it is possible to remove that -1 that I got in the question that would be awesome as it is definitely not duplicate issue as it was though to be